# Could not decrypt file. Read Excel protected file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have excel file and it gives error "Could not decrypt file.". When I open excel file it is opening and not prompt me for any password.

But when I check its protection from toolbar in excel. It shows file is protected.

How can I read that file using OLEDBConnection.

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356051/read-password-protected-excel-file-using-oledb-in-c-sharp useful here.

Comment: maybe is not have permissions to open it.

Comment: Please take a loook at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356051/read-password-protected-excel-file-using-oledb-in-c-sharp/19998406#19998406

Answer (score 0):

I had a user with this issue today... I just told her to either unprotect the worksheet

In my specific case, she actually wasn't able to unprotect the worksheet since it required a password to unprotect it, so I just had her copy/paste the data into a new Excel file instead.