# How Load Excel File With Password In C#

Tags: c#, excel, passwords, xls

I Work On C# Project

I Use Below Code For Import XLS Or XLSX File On DataSet.

```
public static DataSet ImportExcelXLS(string FileName, bool hasHeaders)
{
    string HDR = hasHeaders ? "Yes" : "No";
    string strConn;
    if (FileName.Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
    {
            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
    }
    else
    {
            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
    }

    DataSet output = new DataSet();

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        DataTable schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
            OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

        foreach (DataRow schemaRow in schemaTable.Rows)
        {
            string sheet = schemaRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

            if (!sheet.EndsWith("_"))
            {
                try
                {
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet + "]", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    sheet = sheet.Replace("$", "");
                    DataTable outputTable = new DataTable(sheet);
                    output.Tables.Add(outputTable);
                    new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(outputTable);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message + string.Format("Sheet:{0}.File:F{1}", sheet, FileName), ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

This Code Work Correctly For Load Excel File Without Password. But When Run For Load a File With password Show Under error:

> Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is
>   missing or opened exclusively by another user.

Now How Change My Code For Load Encrypt File?

Comment: You can't open a password-protected Excel workbook in OleDb without first opening it using another method. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1356051/976080).

Answer (score 1):

Please : use this lib:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Please , provide password :

```
WorkbookObject.Password = password;
```

Please, Change ConnString:

```
string conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + s + ";Password=password;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
```

Here, your answer is:

```
 if (FileName.Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
 {
     strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Password=password;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
 }
 else
 {
     strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Password=password;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
 }
```

Comment: how connect WorkbookObject object to my connection string?

Comment: This answer is using two totally different techniques for access Excel: Interop and OleDb. They don't work together particularly well and you certainly won't be able to set a password in Interop by only connecting to a workbook through OleDb.

Answer (score 0):

Try for this code:

```
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Password=password;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
```

but still the exception popped:

> Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user.