# How can I dodge empty rows in an Excel file with OleDB?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

I start to use OleDB. I'm trying to extract a large range of random data from an Excel file (in C#). This my query :

```
SELECT * FROM NAMED_RANGE
```

But I have a lot of empty rows. I delete them in a loop but I don't really like it, is it possible to select only rows with at least one cell filled ?

Best regards,

Alex

Comment: Do you have any knowledge up-front about what rows/columns might have data in them?  Do you have any expectations _at all_ about what the sheet(s) might contain?

Comment: The only thing recurrent is when 10 lines in a row are empty, the next lines will be empty too until the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply change the SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM NAMED_RANGE WHERE [YourColumnTitle] IS NOT NULL
```

Or if [F1] is your Column:

```
SELECT * FROM NAMED_RANGE WHERE F1 IS NOT NULL
```

Thanks to mr.Reband

Comment: If the excel file doesn't have column titles , you can reference column numbers preceded by an 'F', like `WHERE F1 IS NOT NULL`

Comment: The problem here is that unless you know _exactly_ how many columns are possibly to contain data, you would not know how to construct such a SQL.

Comment: It will be ok for an empty **Column** but I have empty **Rows** :/

Comment: @Alex An empty _row_ is nothing more than a collection of empty _columns_.  The solution works, but is tedious because of the unknown number of columns involved.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Ok, I understand. I work on thirty columns, so I guess I have to do "F1 IS NOT NULL ... AND F30 IS NOT NULL".

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately, unless there is more you know about the row going in, that's the best you can do.  Personally, I'd rather just select it all and do it in a code loop, but that's me.