# Importing data from excelsheet file into the mysql database C#

Tags: c#, import-from-excel

I have the following lines of code:

```
     protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        MySqlTransaction transaction;

        string ex_id = "";



        string file_name = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
        string Excel_path = Server.MapPath("~/Excel/" + file_name);
    DataTable dtExceldata = new DataTable();//just added
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Excel_path);

        OleDbConnection my_con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Excel_path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False");
    my_con.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", my_con);
        da.Fill(dtExceldata);
    if (dtExceldata.Rows.Count > 0)             
    {
        //foreach (DataRow row in dtExceldata.Rows)
            for (int i = 0; i <= dtExceldata.Rows.Count - 1; i++)

        {

                string ex_dir = dtExceldata.Rows[i]["website_a"].ToString();
                //string ex_dir = row["website_a"].ToString();


                string ex_email = dtExceldata.Rows[i]["email_id"].ToString();
                // string ex_email = row["email_id"].ToString();


                string ex_email1 = dtExceldata.Rows[i]["email_id2"].ToString();
                //string ex_email1 = row["email_id2"].ToString();


                string ex_email2 = dtExceldata.Rows[i]["email_id3"].ToString();
                //string ex_email2 = row["email_id3"].ToString();


                string ex_company = dtExceldata.Rows[i]["company"].ToString();
                //string ex_company = row["company"].ToString();

                string ex_contact = dtExceldata.Rows[i]["contact_name"].ToString();
                //string ex_contact = row["contact_name"].ToString();


                string ex_proposal = dtExceldata.Rows[i]["proposal_status"].ToString();
                // string ex_proposal = row["proposal_status"].ToString();


                string ex_reason = dtExceldata.Rows[i]["reason"].ToString();
                //string ex_reason = row["reason"].ToString();


        int chk = 0;
            int type = 0;
            int dup = 0;
            int dir = 0;

            if (ddlwebsites.SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
                dir = Convert.ToInt32(ddlwebsites.SelectedValue);
                if (dir == 8)
                {
                    type = 1;
                }

            }


            foreach (ListItem lstAssign in ddlevents.Items)
            {
                if (lstAssign.Selected == true)
                {
                    chk = 1;
                }
            }

            if (type == 1 && chk == 0)
            {
                evyerror.Text = "Please Select the Event!!";
                return;

            }

            else
            {
                string querycomp = "", compID = "";
                querycomp = "Select * from barter_company where website like '%' '" + ex_dir + "' '%'";
                string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BarterConnectionString"].ToString();
                connect = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                connect.Open();
                transaction = connect.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    ClassDtBaseConnect clsDtResult = new ClassDtBaseConnect();
                    DataTable dt = clsDtResult.GetDataTable(querycomp);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        compID = dt.Rows[0]["comp_id"].ToString();
                        ViewState["comp_id"] = compID;
                        if (type == 1)
                        {
                            dup = checkforDuplicates(Convert.ToInt32(compID));
                            if (dup == 1)
                            {
                                //Confirm_MP.Show();
                                // ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "confirmation();", true);
                            }

                        }
                        //return;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        string queryStr = "insert into barter_company (comp_name,website) values(?comp,?website)";
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, connect, transaction);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?comp", ex_company);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?website", ex_dir);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.CommandText = "Select LAST_INSERT_ID()";
                        compID = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                        transaction.Commit();
                        connect.Close();

                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }





                if (dup == 0)
                {
                    // create a connection string with your sql database 
                    string connStr1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BarterConnectionString"].ToString();
                    connect = new MySqlConnection(connStr1);
                    connect.Open();
                    DateTime date = new DateTime();
                    date = DateTime.ParseExact(txtsentdate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
                    string SentDateString = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                    //DateTime date = new DateTime();
                    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ex_date))
                    // {
                    //DateTime date = new DateTime();//added by chetan
                    //ex_date = ex_date.Split(' ')[0];//added by chetan
                    //date = DateTime.ParseExact(ex_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);//added by chetan
                    //string SentDateString = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");//added by chetan
                    //DateTime SentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(SentDateString).Date;//added by chetan
                    //// DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(ex_date);//added by chetan


                    // }
                    //date = DateTime.ParseExact(ex_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//added by chetan
                    //date = DateTime.ParseExact(ex_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
                    // string SentDateString = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                    transaction = connect.BeginTransaction();
                    try
                    {

                        string ex_uid = Session["session_barterUser_id"].ToString();


                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into barter_proposals(user_id, sent_date, website_a, email_id, email_id2, email_id3, company, contact_name, proposal_status, reason,type) values(?uid,?sentdate,?dir,?email,?email2,?email3,?comp,?cont_name,?pro_status,?reason,?type)", connect);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?uid", ex_uid);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?comp", compID);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?sentdate", SentDateString);
                        // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?event", eventname);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?dir", dir);
                        // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?bar_type", ddlbartertype.SelectedValue);
                        // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?website_b", txtwebsite.Text);
                        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?comp", ex_company);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?cont_name", ex_contact);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email", ex_email);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email2", ex_email1);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email3", ex_email2);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pro_status", ex_proposal);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?reason", ex_reason);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?type", type);
                        // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?type", type);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (type == 1)
                        {

                            cmd.CommandText = "Select LAST_INSERT_ID()";
                            Int64 CurrentProId = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                            int eventAssignID;
                            string QueryInqEventAssign = "insert into barter_propeventassign(prop_id,event_id) values(?pro_id,?event_id)";

                            foreach (ListItem lstAssign in ddlevents.Items)
                            {
                                if (lstAssign.Selected == true)
                                {
                                    cmd = new MySqlCommand(QueryInqEventAssign, connect, transaction);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pro_id", CurrentProId);
                                    eventAssignID = Convert.ToInt32(lstAssign.Value);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?event_id", eventAssignID);
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                }
                            }

                        }//end of if
                        transaction.Commit();
                        connect.Close();
                        Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Proposal Added Successfully!!!');</script>");
                    }//end of try
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('There is an Error Ocurred:" + Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message) + "')</script>");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        connect.Close();

                    }

                }//ifdupzero
            }//else
        }//for//foreach
      }//while //if  


   // dr.Close();//commented by chetan

    my_con.Close();
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Excel_path))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(Excel_path);
    }





}
```

suppose there are 2 entries in the excelsheet file.When trying to import,it is inserting those 2 rows entries into the database table.but the problem is that, the reader does not stop its execution.After reading 2 rows entry,it is reading 3rd row which is blank.i have used dr.close and it keeps on reading the rows entries which is blank.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I dodge empty rows in an Excel file with OleDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149948/how-can-i-dodge-empty-rows-in-an-excel-file-with-oledb)

Comment: See also : https://forums.asp.net/t/2029054.aspx?Get+OleDb+reading+from+excel+to+skip+all+empty+rows+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking if there are rows left (dr.Read()) as your loop condition, you could check if the first cell of the row is blank (dr[0].ToString() != String.Empty)

```
string file_name = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            string Excel_path = Server.MapPath("~/Excel/" + file_name);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Excel_path);

            OleDbConnection my_con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Excel_path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False");

            my_con.Open();         
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", my_con);          
            OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();            
            while (dr[0].ToString() != String.Empty)
            {
            ex_id = dr[0].ToString();
            string ex_uid = dr[1].ToString();
            //get second row data and assign it ex_name variable
            string ex_date = dr[2].ToString();
            //get thirdt row data and assign it ex_name variable

            string ex_dir = dr[3].ToString();

            //get first row data and assign it ex_location variable
            string ex_email = dr[4].ToString();
            string ex_email1 = dr[5].ToString();
            string ex_email2 = dr[6].ToString();
            //string ex_company = dr[7].ToString();
            string ex_company = dr[7].ToString();
            string ex_contact = dr[8].ToString();
            string ex_proposal = dr[9].ToString();
            string ex_reason = dr[10].ToString();
               ...............
               //Insert operation
               ...............
            dr.Read();
            }
            dr.close();
            my_con.close();
```

The premise of course is, that the first column is always filled if the rest of the row isn't blank.
If that isn't the case you can also check other columns in the loop condition.

Comment: I am reading data from the excel file....1st row contains Uid Name Emailid Contactname........2nd row contains the details like  1 rahul a@gmail.com Raunak..........3rd row contains 2 vishal b@g.com vish......it is reading this 2nd and 3rd row and inserted it into a database but the problem is it is not stopping...it goes to read 4th row which is blank..and i have used session for uid..so stores the value of uid into the database and other columns blank

Comment: Is there a column in the excel file that is filled in every row?

Comment: no....its like uid name emailid emaiid1 contactname.....its details are 1 rahul a@er.com   blankcell   rahul

Comment: So the uid is always filled? If so you could change the loop condition to "while (dr[1].ToString() != String.Empty)"

Comment: uid is autoincrement...i am just keeping it blank always...uid is not going from excel file....i have used session for uid

Comment: you could also check for multiple fields in your loop condition like "while (dr[0].ToString() != String.Empty && dr[1].ToString() != String.Empty)" and so on

Comment: ignore uid....if i take Name Emailid Contactname.....dr[0] 2nd row shd be rahul and dr[1] shd b a@gmail.com and dr[3] shd be raunak...rite?

Answer (score 1):

there is various way of doing that
you can load excel data to datatable and then you can for loop for each row with perticular column name like this

```
string file_name = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    string Excel_path = Server.MapPath("~/Excel/" + file_name);
    DataTable dtExceldata = new DataTable();
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Excel_path);
    OleDbConnection my_con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Excel_path + ";Extended 

Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False");
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", my_con);
        da.Fill(dtExceldata);
        if(dtExceldata.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= dtExceldata.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                //assign value to variable
                //like below
                //string ex_uid = dtExceldata.Rows[i]["columnName"]; 
                //then insert operation here

            }
    }
```

Comment: @Ankit...suppose there are 2 rows ...it is inserting those 2 rows into the database...bt execution is not stoping...in your case i++ is there...2+1 is 3 so i dont have 3rd row in my excel file...it is reading it as blank..only 2 rows should be read if i have 2 rows in excel file

Comment: is there any way to close the connection after reading 2 rows so that it does not read 3rd row which is blank???

Comment: this loop will repeat for only number of row in datatable then also i practically tried this and it only loop for number of row (e.g two times) but i found a bug that if you will enter two row then five row blank then some data it will give you blank value in data table check your excel file there may some blank value

Answer (score 0):

see this excel file
[image]

and the datatable in c#
[image]

this loop will repeat for only number of row in datatable then also i practically tried this and it only loop for number of row (e.g two times) but i found a bug that if you will enter two row then five blank row then some data it will give you blank value in data table check your excel file there may some blank value as shown in attechment
then also you can skip blank value by checking null value in row like this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dtExceldata.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dtExceldata.Rows[i]["fieldvalues"])))
                {
                    //assign value to variable
                    //like below
                    //string ex_uid = dtExceldata.Rows[i]["columnName"]; 
                    //then insert operation here
                }
            }
```

Comment: i checked there is no other values in excel file

Comment: i am getting the output like below in db table:

uid      website_a    email_id    emailid_2 email_id3  company
1           a            b                               d
2           x            y                               z
3           blank       blank                           blank 
and it goes on..

first 2 rows are ok...it should insert only those 2 rows from excel but it reads 3rd 4th and insert and so on.

Comment: @Ankit...i have edited the code.....I have added the full code of import data....suggest some changes if u find any....