# Get data from excel (xlsx) by vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledbconnection

How to Read a password protected excel file

What I need is read Password protected excel file using OLEDB Connection 
If any one have solution to resolve this problem please let me know...
thank you

this work when there is no password

```
conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;'")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read password protected excel file using OLEDB in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356051/read-password-protected-excel-file-using-oledb-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Let us know if the above link does not solve your problem.

Comment: i need it with vb.net can any one help

Comment: Is it the entire Excel file that is password protected, or is it only one or more worksheets?

Comment: it is the entire Excel file that is password protected

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if you try to open a password-protected Excel workbook from VB.NET, you get an error message “Could not decrypt file”. Adding a `Password=` value to your connection string won’t work either.

To get around this problem, first open the Excel workbook using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.GetObject()` and then open it using the connection / recordset approach that you want to use. The `GetObject()` open prompts your user for the password, and then you are free to open the file using your preferred approach. For example:

```
' Open the Excel workbook to prompt for the password
Dim xl As Object
xl = GetObject(CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "MASTER JAN 2009.xls")
' Adding your code here should work as the workbook will be opened and so
' you should be able to connect to it.
```

Of course, your user has to know the password.

This solution was taken from [Open a password-protected Excel workbook](https://www.connectionstrings.com/how-to-open-password-protected-excel-workbook/).