# Openrowset password protected excel file

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

I am getting the below error message and am trying to find the correct syntax to specify the user id/password to connect to the excel file. Can you help with how this should be input?

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''.
> It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.".
> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 58
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

```
    SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(
'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;
Database=filename;
HDR=YES;',
'SELECT * FROM sheetname')
```

Comment: If [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1356051/4137916) are any indication, you can't do this, because the OLEDB driver can't read password-protected files, period. The workarounds are mostly inapplicable to code running from SQL Server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming, I will try another method.